# Unable to get google app for verification

Tags: google-developers-console, google-cloud-console

When I use google OAuth for login verification, there's warning pop up with
​
`Google hasn’t verified this app The app is requesting access to sensitive info in your Google Account. Until the developer verifies this app with Google, you shouldn't use it.`

I want this warning to disappear and I tried to submit my app for verification in google cloud console and it does't work. I notice it said "verification not required". Is that mean I don't need to submit it for verification?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpWgU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should still send verification one more time to google and you need to give your scope permissions clearly so they should be permissions without restriction keys to be verified faster

I have learned about this issue, you need to provide Google with full information and explain your use of permissions in the application. Official documentation here
[link here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/13463073?visit_id=638436722807023813-3815500318&hl=en&rd=1#sensitive-scope-verification)